# MySQL error #1054 - Unknown column in 'Field List'

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

Whenever I try to input data into my tblorder I get the error message #1054 - Unknown column 'FK_Customer_ID' in 'field list'. 
I have tried breaking my code down and in doing this I found that the error is repeated for FK_Customer_ID and OrderQuantity whereas FK_DVD_ID it will take single data entries. I have tried dropping the table and recreating it, I have dropped the database and recreated it but nothing works. As far as I can tell my code is correct along with my spelling so I'm really stuck.

My tblorder is-

```
CREATE TABLE tblorder
(   
 Order_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,  
 FK_Customer_ID INT NOT NULL,   
 FK_DVD_ID INT NOT NULL,    
 OrderDate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
 OrderQantity INT NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (Order_ID),    
 FOREIGN KEY (FK_Customer_ID) REFERENCES tblcustomer (Customer_ID), 
 FOREIGN KEY (FK_DVD_ID) REFERENCES tbldvd (PK_ID)
);
```

The data I am trying to put in is-

```
INSERT INTO tblorder
 (FK_Customer_ID, FK_DVD_ID, OrderQuantity)
VALUES 
 (1, 3, 2),
 (1, 5, 1),
 (1, 10, 4), 
 (1, 15, 3),
 (2, 5, 4),
 (2, 17, 3),
 (3, 15, 1),
 (3, 16, 1),
 (3, 17, 1);
```

FK_Customer_ID is addressing -

```
CREATE TABLE tblcustomer
(
 Customer_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
 FirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 Age INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (Customer_ID)
);
```

FK_DVD_ID is addressing -

```
CREATE TABLE tblDVD
(
 PK_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
 Title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 DIrector VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 Genre VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
 dvd_Year YEAR NOT NULL,
 Price FLOAT(2) NOT NULL,
 Quantity INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (PK_ID)
);
```

Any help in fixing the will be greatly appreciated as it will help me with my A2 computing lesson!

Comment: Use phpmyadmin to create your tables including the foreign key contraints and compare wigh what you got.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have an error in your OrderQuantity column. It is named "OrderQuantity" in the INSERT statement and "OrderQantity" in the table definition.

Also, I don't think you can use `NOW()` as default value in OrderDate. Try to use the following:

```
 OrderDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7db7/1/0)

Answer (score 2):

This, for me, was one of those incredibly stupid errors (on my part), but it took a lot of time to hunt it down.  I created a new table, and got the #1054 error repeatedly, even though the table did have the 'unknown column'.

Then as I was gazing at the table definition wondering what the problem was, I noticed that the column names, almost imperceptibly, didn't perfectly line up vertically on the columns list.

Turns out there was a SPACE that snuck into the column name definition.  DOH!  So instead of 'colName' the actual column name was ' colName'.  Hence the error msg.

I know this is dumb, but sometimes errors are like that.  Just thought I'd mention it, in case this problem is lurking there for someone else.

Answer (score -1):

I had this error aswell.

I am working in mysql workbench. When giving the values they have to be inside "". That solved it for me.

Answer (score -2):

I've just encountered the same problem, but for me the fix was different; I had a mismatched between the column name in the table I was updating and the column name in a history table, which is updated by a trigger. Correcting this mismatch fixed the problem immediately.